# Slicebox, Linking the images

Tags: javascript, gallery

I'm using slicebox on my homepage but I want to make the images linkable to different pages.

If you add  tags to the images Slicebox will not load!

Doing `onclick="redirectPage()"` makes Slicebox work but nothing happens when you click on the images!

Can anyone help?

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/05/slicebox-3d-image-slider/

My site:
http://www.genyx.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" data-page="/page1.html" title="Creative Lifesaver"/>
    <img src="images/2.jpg" data-page="/page2.html" title="Honest Entertainer"/>
    <img src="images/3.jpg" data-page="/page3.html" title="Brave Astronaut"/>
    <img src="images/4.jpg" data-page="/page4.html" title="Affectionate Decision Maker"/>
    <img src="images/5.jpg" data-page="/page5.html" title="Faithful Investor"/>
    <img src="images/6.jpg" data-page="/page6.html" title="Groundbreaking Artist"/>
    <img src="images/7.jpg" data-page="/page7.html" title="Selfless Philantropist"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#sb-slider img").click(function(){
   window.location.href = $(this).attr("data-page");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunatly that doesn't work either!
I think I'm going to have to find an alternative to slicebox.